# s3cmd configure doesn't accept a remote path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm trying to configure for a client's server s3cmd so we can run backup scripts on it.
I can connect to and list buckets using Transmission (for Mac) but server is Linux and I need s3cmd.

On transmission I input the following information (redacted because of NDA):

```
address: s3.amazonaws.com
Access key: [redacted]
Secret: [redacted]
**Remote path: domain.com**
```

On Mac, like I said, this works and I can list buckets. The fully qualified name for the bucket is: https://domain.com.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname .

With s3cmd, though, I can't seem to figure out how to input the same information.

I tried setting DNS-style bucket+hostname:port template for accessing a bucket: https://domain.com.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname and variations, like changing bucketname to %(bucket)s, us-west-2 to %(location)s. Nothing works.

Is there any way I can solve this?

Thanks for any input, I really appreciate it.

[edit]

I ended up saving the config just to create it, and edited the configuration to reflect the correct paths. But this still should be handled from the --configure, not from editing the configuration file.

Comment: **Side-note:** These days, it is recommend to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: Yeah, my employer also said I should use aws-sdk, but I don't know how to yet, I made do with what I know. I got the above situation working by hand editing the s3cmd configuration file.

Comment: I am suggesting the AWS CLI, not an AWS SDK. It's easy to use -- install it, run `aws configure` to give it the credentials, then you can use commands like `aws s3 sync` to copy data. Plenty of documentation and videos online!